# React.JS creating toggle switch with state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, onclick, react-props

Currently I have a toggle switch from the Semantic UI React library and I am setting the `checked` property to be defaulted to `false` on the page.

I want to make it toggable so the user can click on it but I need to add a OnClick event property. I want to create a function to handle this but I don't want to use state hooks which were introduced in React.JS version 16 and am not sure how to go about it.

Here is my `ToggleSwitch.tsx` file where I create the toggle switch

```
    import * as React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import * as PropTypes from "prop-types";

const ToggleSwitch = ({ id, name,label, checked, onclick }) => {

    return (
        <Checkbox
            name={name}
            id={id}
            label={label}
            checked={checked}
            onclick={onclick}
            toggle

        />
    );
}

ToggleSwitch.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    checked: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    onclick: PropTypes.func,
   
};

export default ToggleSwitch;
```

I then insert the switch into my `subheader.tsx` which creates a subheader across multiple pages on my website which now will have this switch

```
import * as React from "react";
import ToggleSwitch from './new_layout/ToggleSwitch'

interface Props {
    name: string;
  renderAction?: () => any;
}




const SubHeader: React.SFC<Props> = ({ name, renderAction }) => {
    return (
        <div className="settings-submenu">
            <div className="settings-submenu-name">{name}</div>
            <div className="settings-submenu-name">{renderAction && renderAction()}</div>
            <ToggleSwitch name='LayoutToggleSwitch' label='Enable New Layout' id='LayoutToggleSwitch' checked={false} onclick = {} />

        </div>
    
  );
};

export default SubHeader;
```

I am not sure what to put in my `OnClick` function to make this switch able to be switched as currently when I click on it, it does not change from its `checked` value which is `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `checked` attribute will prevent you from changing the state of the checkbox by clicking on it: You should probably use `defaultChecked={false}`.

However, you will still need some state management at some point if you want to interact with the checkbox: You can either use hooks (the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) provides a *really* easy-to-follow introduction to the `useState` hook), or use a state object you will update on click and pass to the checked attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use useState in subHeader component and initialize it with false as the default value.

```
const [newLayoutEnabled, setNewLayoutEnabled] = useState(false);

const handleToggleSwitchClick = () => {
   setNewLayoutEnabled(!newLayoutEnabled);
}
```

And then pass `newLayoutEnabled` and `handleToggleSwitchClick` to ToggleSwitch component.